# Remove Logo image from navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have added the navigationController in my application. I have added the logo in the centre of navigationBar. I just want to remove the logo image from my particular class. For example, in the main page I need that logo image.  In the second view, I do not need that logo. How to remove the logo image for particular view.

Comment: What code you have written for setting up the logo might be useful for others to understand & answer. Can you post that here?

Answer (score 0):

**Best way is**
have a reference of the image view and remove it during navigating to other view by calling

```
[imageView removeFromSuperview];
```

If you add image in UIBarbutton then you can remove it by assign it nil during navigation.

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

If you add image in Title view then you can remove it by assign it nil during navigation.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = nil;
```

---

**Not asked but as more information**
if you have code for navigating at so many places and you do not want to repeat code..
use [delegate method of navigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UINavigationControllerDelegate/navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:)

```
navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main page ViewController, you should add this code:

```objective-c
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // here you should add your logo image
    [self addLogoInNavigationBar];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWllDisappear:animated];
    // here you should remove logo image from navigationBar
    [self removeLogoInNavigationBar];
}
```